# DropDownList preenchido e selecionado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdownlist

Preciso preencher um @Html.DropDownList() com os parâmetros da minha Model e pré selecionar um dos ítens.

Na Model estou recebendo o pacote completo, sendo: Lista de produtos no `Produto` e os itens selecionados através do `MotivosRel`.

Model

```
 public class MotivosModel 
 {    
    public Produto[] ProdutoCollection { get; set; }

    public partial class Produto
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }        
    public class MotivosRel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Motivo Motivo { get; set; }
        public SubMotivo1 SubMotivo1 { get; set; }
        public SubMotivo2 SubMotivo2 { get; set; }
        public SubMotivo3 SubMotivo3 { get; set; }
        public Frase Frase { get; set; }
        public Produto Produto { get; set; }
        public SubProduto SubProduto { get; set; }
        public string Ativo { get; set; }
        public int isNew { get; set; }
        public bool isSelect { get; set; }         
    }
 }
```

Minha dificuldade está em popular o @Html.DropDownList() com `ProdutoCollection` e pré selecionar um deles usando o `Codigo` que está vindo da `MotivosRel.Produto`.

Sabendo que essa tela será para alteração, possibilitando o usuário a selecionar outro produto, sendo assim preciso ter o retorno do código quando salvar.

Obrigado antecipadamente.

Comment: Veja se [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382311/populating-a-razor-dropdownlist-from-a-listobject-in-mvc) pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MotivosRelacionados.Produto.Codigo,
                                    ((IEnumerable<ITAU.SOAS.Aplicativos.CockPit.Model.MotivosModel.Produto>)Model.ProdutoCollection).Select(option => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = option.Nome,
                                        Value = option.Codigo.ToString(),
                                        Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Codigo == Model.MotivosRelacionados.Produto.Codigo)
                                    }), null, null)
```